# need to read Spo2 and PRbpm from Pulse oximeter

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is the JSON that i have found. The service UUID is : `636F6D2E-6A69-7561-6E2E-504F56313100` and characteristic UUID is : `7274782E-6A69-7561-6E2E-504F56313100` for reading the data from oximeter, I only have these two things, **but i dont know what Hex i need to send to retrive the SpO2 and PRbpm.**

```
{
  "name": "Pulse Oximeter",
  "id": "D0:5F:B8:3D:4D:25",
  "rssi": -65,
  "services": [
    "1800",
    "1801",
    "636f6d2e-6a69-7561-6e2e-504f56313100",
    "180a"
  ],
  "characteristics": [
    {
      "service": "1800",
      "characteristic": "2a00",
      "properties": [
        "Read",
        "WriteWithoutResponse",
        "Write"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1800",
      "characteristic": "2a01",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1800",
      "characteristic": "2a02",
      "properties": [
        "Read",
        "Write"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1800",
      "characteristic": "2a03",
      "properties": [
        "Write"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1800",
      "characteristic": "2a04",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1801",
      "characteristic": "2a05",
      "properties": [
        "Indicate"
      ],
      "descriptors": [
        {
          "uuid": "2902"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "636f6d2e-6a69-7561-6e2e-504f56313100",
      "characteristic": "7274782e-6a69-7561-6e2e-504f56313100",
      "properties": [
        "WriteWithoutResponse",
        "Write",
        "Notify"
      ],
      "descriptors": [
        {
          "uuid": "2902"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "2901"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a23",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a24",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a25",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a26",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a27",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a28",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a29",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a2a",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a50",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a30",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a31",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the oximeter device model?

Comment: @Naz141 https://ihealthlabs.com/fitness-devices/wireless-pulse-oximeter/

Comment: Did you check on their given SDKs of iHealthLabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ihealthlabs SDK and documentation is available here https://github.com/iHealthDeviceLabs/iHealthDeviceLabs-Android . and also the free example project is available which you can use it to retrieve data (SpO2 and PRbpm) out of the supported list given in their documentation

Comment: Checking it now

Comment: The GitHub project is not found. Is it deleted or moved to other project ?